# Next in the sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

**Find the next pattern in the sequence :**

> S5VIIN, T12XN, T11XIIIN, S18XVIN, N17XIXN, ?

Comment: You don't need to put the "difficulty" in the question. Also, [number-sequence] puzzles are usually not very popular here unless they're VERY clever - this one isn't.

Comment: Oops sorry! I'm new to stack exchange. I dint know these. I'll give a harder one next time :). Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Not a problem at all! I suggest coming up with some puzzle of your own - maybe a word search or a maze with a secret trick to it, or even something else never seen before! It can be hard, but if it's really creative, we'll all love it. c:

Comment: Yes the puzzles I've given till now is my own :)

Comment: I know! But many of them have been very similar to puzzles I've seen before - this one in particular is just a lot of simple things put next to each other.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound like I'm discouraging you - I'm really not! I want you to make more puzzles and get better, and we'd be happy to help you improve!

Comment: No not at all. These are good responses which would help me improve myself better. Thanks a ton :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's

> T24XXIIO

The sequence is

> 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, ... where each number is first letter + number ±2 (alternate) + roman numeral + last letter

Comment: Close. But not the right one.

Comment: Now it's perfect !

Comment: @Bharatwaaj: If you think an answer completely answers the puzzle or question you have, you can click the checkmark to the left to accept it! Will will get 15 reputation points, and you'll get a bonus  of 2 reputation for picking an answer.